# indentation and whitespaces end up in .aspx markup

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio

I'm having the problem that indentation and whitespaces from the .aspx designer end up in the final markup. 
For example with the YUI3 Grids i have some controls which will render divs with the correct CSS etc. If i use the auto-format function in visual studio (CTRL-E-D) it puts each control on a new line, which results in linebreaks in the final .aspx page and the YUI3 Grids breaks.

Example:

```
<YUI:Grid runat="server">
    <YUI:Unit UnitWidth="1-2" runat="server">
        1/2</YUI:Unit>
    <YUI:Unit UnitWidth="1-2" runat="server">
        1/2</YUI:Unit>
</YUI:Grid>
```

This results in:

```
<div class="yui3-grid">

    <div class=" yui3-u-1-2">

        1/2
    </div>
    <div class=" yui3-u-1-2">

        1/2
    </div>

</div>
```

But

```
<YUI:Grid runat="server">
    <YUI:Unit UnitWidth="1-2" runat="server">1/2</YUI:Unit><YUI:Unit UnitWidth="1-2" runat="server">1/2</YUI:Unit>
</YUI:Grid>
```

Renders as

```
<div class="yui3-grid">

    <div class=" yui3-u-1-2">
        1/2
    </div><div class=" yui3-u-1-2">
        1/2
    </div>

</div>
```

Not using the auto-format isn't an option. I've looked into the HTML Designer options of Visual Studio without finding anything.

At the moment i'm removing the whitespaces and line breaks in the render event of the page by regex. Isn't there an other option, a switch somewhere...?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've a feeling that you mix up VS-Autoformat of the HTML-Designer with rendered HTML from ASP.NET.

Comment: It doesn't matter if i format it by myself or with the VS-Autoformat function. As long each tag is on a new line i get these linebreaks also in the final markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem lay in the `yui3-grid` class, it should have been `yui3-g`

Now it works even with linebreaks & empty spaces between tags. Maybe i'm going to keep the code for removing whitespaces, have to test how